# Resizing rectangle on Pan & Zoom Axes

Tags: d3.js

I've added rectangles to Mike Bostock’s Pan & Zoom Axes example but I can't get the rectangle to resize with the zoomed in axes.   I have added remove and append/enter to the zoomed function but it doesn't execute.  Any help would be appreciated.

```
gMain.selectAll(".rectband").remove();

        shape = gMain.selectAll('.rectband')
           .data(data)
           .enter()
           .append('rect')
           .attr("fill", "blue")
           .attr("width", 100)
           .attr("height", 100);
```

https://bl.ocks.org/mbostock/db6b4335bf1662b413e7968910104f0f

Comment: you may need to call "zoom" again.

Comment: How do I access the zoomed x and y coordinates for the update?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [d3 version 4 zoom behaviour on g element](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38544216/d3-version-4-zoom-behaviour-on-g-element)

Answer (score 1):

Final solution is utilised in this fiddle:

https://jsfiddle.net/u6rj20jc/3/

```
 function zoomed() {
        view.attr("transform", d3.event.transform);
        gX.call(xAxis.scale(d3.event.transform.rescaleX(x)));
        gY.call(yAxis.scale(d3.event.transform.rescaleY(y)));

        gMain.attr("transform", d3.event.transform);
        group.attr("transform", d3.event.transform);
       }
```